# Does Facebook return Album location information

Tags: facebook

When you fetch an album from Facebook, does it also return the WHERE information of the album so you will know where the album is taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. If the album was tagged with the location where it was taken, it can be retrieved from the `location` in the JSON reponse.

For example:

```
   {
      "id": "...", 
      "from": {
        "name": "...", 
        "id": "..."
      }, 
      "name": "Brussels", 
      "location": "Brussels", 
     ....
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It does, it's listed as "location"

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Is a good tool for playing around with the api and seeing what you can access